# How do I graph subtotals in Microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

We're just getting started with Microstrategy and have created a few reports. One of the reports I'm working on needs to be a grid/graph and I'm struggling with how to  get the graph to display what we need.

Our Grid report looks like this:

```
Report_Date 4/30/2013   5/1/2013    5/2/2013    5/5/2013    5/6/2013    5/7/2013    5/8/2013    5/9/2013    5/10/2013   5/14/2013
Metrics  GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power   GiB/Power
Tester                                      
WMC440002913    0   0.62    1.19    0.41    0.91    2.49    1.32    4.48    0.17
WMC440003719    0   6.6     5.3     5.29    7.64    4.72        0   5.51    
WMC450001681    0   1.83    0.9 0.41    1.83    1.02    1.72    0.57    
Total           0   7.22    8.33    6.6 8.95    6.55    3.51    3.04    10.57   0.17
Average         0   3.61    2.78    2.2 2.98    3.27    1.75    1.01    3.52    0.17
```

(Sorry for the word wrap)

What I want to be able to graph is the Subtotals (Total and Average) with Date as the X-Axis. The grid side needs to be like it is here. I've tried everything I can think of but I can't seem to graph the subtotals not get the Date as the X-Axis.

Graph should look like the attached sample.

[image: Sample of Graph]
I've searched these forums, the documentation and  even scoured the tutorials with no luck.

Hopefully someone up here has a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you have already a metric GiB/Power, that I expect is defined as Sum(GiB/Power){~}.

Create a second metric called Avg GiB/Power with formula Avg(GiB/Power), then create a grid with only:

- Report_Date
- GiB/Power
- Avg GiB/Power

Then in the Report Data Options -> Display -> Alias change:

- GiB/Power to Total
- Avg GiB/Power to Average

At this point you should be able to get the graph that you need.